# Calculating the expectation of $\frac{1}{|W \cap W_{tU}|}$ where W is a square with side $a$.

Tags: integration, geometry, random-variables, area, expected-value

I am dealing with a following problem: Calculate
$$\mathbb{E}f(tU), t \geq 0$$
where U is a random variable with uniform distribution on the unit circle and 
$$f(h)=\frac{1}{|W \cap W_h|}$$ where $W$ is a square with side $a$ and $W_h$ is $W$ translated by the vector $h$. $|S|$ denotes the area of $S$. I would like to get an answer in closed form as a function of t. Is this possible?
So far, I've gotten to
$$ \mathbb{E}f(tU)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{||u||=1}\frac{1}{|W \cap W_{tu}|} \mathrm{d}u = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{||u||=1}\frac{1}{(a-t|u_1|)(a-t|u_2|)} \mathrm{d}u_1\mathrm{d}u_2. $$
I assume that $a \geq 1$, since i will be probably using the result for $a=1$. So far, I've had no luck dealing with this integral and I am starting to think that it might not have a closed form. Would this maybe be possible for $W$ being a disk?

Comment: I am trying to integrate the area of the intersection of two squares over the unit circle. Could you please elaborate on how to get a 1d integral which has closed form? By substituting into polar coordinates i get $$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{(a-t|cos(\alpha)|)(a-t|sin(\alpha)|)} \mathrm{d}\alpha $$. I have not been able to evaluate this integral.

Comment: Side note: $a$ and $t$ are parameters, which can vary(the result will be used in another calculation where i integrate over t).

Comment: $\color{red}{1.}$ The integral in your *comment* is what has to go to the *question*. I see "$\mathrm{d}u_1\mathrm{d}u_2$" there - it doesn't look like an "1D integral" and causes the confusion. $\color{red}{2.}$ Introducing $\beta=t/a$ (to have fewer parameters) and using the obvious symmetry, it boils down to $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}\alpha}{(1-\beta\cos\alpha)(1-\beta\sin\alpha)},$$ manageable with $x=\tan(\alpha/2)$ (yeah, some work is to be done, but you can try it yourself first). $\color{red}{3.}$ For *disk*, isn't it a *constant* under the integral?

Comment: To clarify the confusion: the integral with $du_1 du_2$ is not a 1D integral. It is an integral where we integrate the quantity in the integral over the unit circle, which i denoted $||u||=1$, sorry if that confused you.

Comment: Solving the integral $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}\alpha}{(1-b cos\alpha)(1-b sin \alpha)}$$ in Mathematica yielded the following for $b \in (0,1)$: $$\frac{2 \left(\left(b^2-1\right) \log (1-b)+\sqrt{1-b^2} \left(-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{b-1}{\sqrt{1-b^2}}\right)+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{b+1}{\sqrt{1-b^2}}\right)+\sin ^{-1}(b)\right)\right)}{b^4-3 b^2+2}$$. I believe this is what I am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See comments under the question. Introducing $b=t/a$ in the first equality, $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{(a-t|cos(\alpha)|)(a-t|sin(\alpha)|)} \mathrm{d}\alpha = \frac{1}{a^2} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{(1-b|cos(\alpha)|)(1-b|sin(\alpha)|)} \mathrm{d}\alpha = \\ = \frac{1}{a^2}4\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}\alpha}{(1-\beta\cos\alpha)(1-\beta\sin\alpha)}.$$

Solving the last integral in Mathematica yielded the following for ∈(0,1): 
$$\frac{4}{a^2}\frac{2 \left(\left(b^2-1\right) \log (1-b)+\sqrt{1-b^2} \left(-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{b-1}{\sqrt{1-b^2}}\right)+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{b+1}{\sqrt{1-b^2}}\right)+\sin ^{-1}(b)\right)\right)}{b^4-3 b^2+2}.$$